# Cannot unset session variable after echo

Tags: php, html, session, unset

I have an error message stored in a session variable that I want to show only once. My method is to check if it's there, then echo it and unset it after.

```html
<div class="signin">

  <form name="signuser" action="php/signin_user.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['signin']['email']; ?>"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
  </form>

  <br>
  <div id="login-error" style="display: none"></div>
  
  <?php

  if(isset($_SESSION['msg']['signin-error'])) { 
      echo '<div id="login-php-error">';
echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['msg']['signin-error'].'</p>';
      echo '</div>';
}

  if(isset($_SESSION['msg']['signin-error'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['msg']['signin-error']);
  }

  if (isset($_SESSION['signin']['email']))
      unset($_SESSION['signin']['email']);

  ?>

</div>
```

I have tried with != "" as well:

```html
<?php

  if($_SESSION['msg']['signin-error'] != "") { 
    echo '<div id="login-php-error">';
    echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['msg']['signin-error'].'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
  }

  if($_SESSION['msg']['signin-error'] != "") {
    unset($_SESSION['msg']['signin-error']);
  }

  if ($_SESSION['signin']['email'] != "")
    unset($_SESSION['signin']['email']);

?>
```

Nothing works. I have session_start() on all of my pages. It still shows up each refresh.

**EDIT:**

Obviously I am new to PHP and I see now that using session to give user feedback is silly. I ended up using GET to display error messages and it works great for my need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you need to start the session if you haven't already

Comment: I have <?php session_start(); ?> ontop off all my pages

Comment: check for errors then http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - view html source, `var_dump()` and echo are all useful debugging tools.

Comment: you're also doing this twice `if($_SESSION['msg']['signin-error'] != "")` and we don't know where/how those session arrays are set as.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have tried many things, and that was one of them.

Comment: why do u even store error message on a session when u want to use it once?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile It's common practice in frameworks (see for example the flashbag in Symfony or the FlashMessenger in Zend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are declared in the header. Headers are sent before any other content and `echo`'ing content/or just having text (e.g. HTML) will end the headers. That means you can't change sessions after `echo`'ing.

There is however a way around using PHP [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php). You use `ob_start()` at the start of your script and `ob_end_flush()` at the end. Using these functions you can edit sessions after echo'ing content.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/5914775) for more information.

**Edit:**
As @ccKep said you can still change the `$_SESSION` variable (`$_SESSION['something'] = 'else'`) after sending the headers. You just can't start or destroy a session after the headers have been sent.

Comment: This might be a bit confusing, ofcourse you can change `$_SESSION` variables even after already sending output. It's the `session_start` that has to come before it (since it declares the session id in the cookie).